# Loop to divide years into two parts

Tags: r, xts, tidyverse, quantmod, performanceanalytics

I am looking for a way to create a loop that divides multiple years into a beginning sections and ending sections and gives numerical values at with percentage of the year that cut took place. It is probably easiest to show you the product that I want to get before I describe more in detail:

The first iteration of the loop would give me the following output to work with before the next iteration starts:

```
beginning_section = c("2003-01-01/2003-02-01","2004-01-01/2004-02-01","2005-01-01/2005-02-01")
ending_section = c("2003-02-02/2003-12-31","2004-02-02/2004-12-31","2005-02-02/2005-12-31")
time_scale = c(0.169,0.169,0.169)
```

Second iteration of the loop would give me the following output to work with before the next iteration starts:

```
beginning_section = c("2003-01-01/2003-02-02","2004-01-01/2004-02-02","2005-01-01/2005-02-02")
ending_section = c("2003-02-03/2003-12-31","2004-02-03/2004-12-31","2005-02-03/2005-12-31")
time_scale = c(0.172,0.172,0.172)
```

Last iteration of the loop would give me the following output to work with before the loop concludes:

```
beginning_section = c("2003-01-01/2003-11-30","2004-01-01/2004-11-30","2005-01-01/2005-11-30")
ending_section = c("2003-02-03/2003-12-31","2004-02-03/2004-12-31","2005-02-03/2005-12-31")
time_scale = c(0.915,0.915,0.915)

#do some calculations with beginning_section, ending section, and time scaled
```

Basically, it should divide all years at a specific month-day point, into two character-vectors (one for all the beginning sections and one for all the ending sections) and give an integer-vector, which shows at what percentage of the year the cut was made. The cut-off would for example be 0.5 if the cut happened right in the middle of the year. The loop should then should move one day forward and do the same thing again, and so forth.

What I have tried (and have failed absolutely miserable with) so far:

```
library(tidyverse)   

days <- 1:30 %>% as.character()
months <- 2:11 %>% as.character()
years <- 2003:2017 %>% as.character()

beg_section <- NULL
end_section <- NULL
time_scaled <- NULL

for (m in months) {
  for (d in days) {
    for (y in years) {
      temp_beg <- paste(y, "-1-1/", y, "-", m, "-", d, sep = "")
      beg_section <- rbind(beg_section,temp_beg)
      temp_end <- paste(y, "-", m, "-", d, "/", y, "-12-31", sep = "")
      end_section <- rbind(end_section,temp_end)
      temp_scale <- (as.numeric(m) + as.numeric(d)/30 - 1) / 12
      time_scaled <- rbind(time_scaled,temp_scale)
    }
  }
} 

beg_section <- beg_section %>% as.vector()
end_section <- end_section %>% as.vector()
time_scaled <- time_scaled %>% as.vector()

n <- 1
m <- length(years) %>% as.numeric()

while (m < length(beg_section)) {
  lead_up_period <- beg_section[n:m]
  end_period <- end_section[n:m]
  vol_adjustment <- time_scaled[n]
  print(lead_up_period)
  print(end_period)
  print(vol_adjustment)
  n <- m + 1
  m <- m + length(years)
    }
#end
```

I'd also like to note that the solution does not have to be absolutely perfect. If for example all the months only deal with 30 days, that would already be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please add an example of your expected output.

Comment: Why insist on using  *loops* to achieve your goals? In R vectoriized approaches are preferable.

Comment: @JohnColeman: I am not insisting. It is just the option that came to mind with my limited understanding of R and programming in general. If you know a different and better way, please let me know.